# Einstein chatbot - how to allow user to change option menu they selected

Tags: chatbot

Once User select the option from option menu, menu become disabled and user can not change the choice. we have a requirement where user should be able to go back and change the selection. Is there a way to achieve this ?

[Update 25/01/2023]
we are using bot option menu to display options. we have a complex process flow where BOT ask multiple questions (some are option menu, some are number field, some are just text etc). Bot shows the next dialogue based on previous selection and at the end create either a lead or case.

now unlike web page or screen flow there is no back button , and if user make the wrong selection or enter wrong answer to any of the question, there is no way to go back and they have to start all over again.

For example

first question is as below

[image]

After answering first , BOT ask second question as below

[image]

Then Third question as below

[image]

At this point , if customer realise he answered wrong choice in first or second one, they can not go back and re-select the another option, as that is disabled.

I am looking to find a solution for this

Comment: Can you include a screenshot/clickpath of option menu for better understanding? Thanks

Comment: Hi Swetha, Updated the query

Comment: have you found the solution? @DineshKhandelwal